# Как правильно реализовать шаблон «Состояние» на Unity?

Tags: unity3d, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу реализовать шаблон "Cостояние".

С этой целью я создал абстрактный класс "GameState" и пустой Gameobject в представлении Hierarchy с тем же именем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стало ясно, что невозможно присоединить сценарий с абстрактным классом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда я прикрепил к скрипту "GameState" GameObject с классом "GameManager":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

GameState.cs:

```
 public abstract class GameState : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField]
     protected static GameObject gameManagerObject;
     protected GameManager gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GameManager>();

     internal virtual void HandleButton(GameManager gameManager, PressedButton button)
     {
         ChangeState(gameManager, button);
     }

     protected abstract void ChangeState(GameManager gameManager, PressedButton button);

 }

 internal class StartState : GameState
 {
     internal StartState()
     {
         Debug.Log("Launch game");
     }

     protected override void ChangeState(GameManager gameManager, PressedButton button)
     {
         gameManager.State = new WorkState();
     }
 }

 internal class WorkState : GameState
 {
     internal WorkState()
     {
         gameManager.DoSomething(false);
     }

     protected override void ChangeState(GameManager gameManager, PressedButton button)
     {
         gameManager.State = new PauseState();
     }
 }

 internal class PauseState : GameState
 {
     internal PauseState()
     {
         Debug.Log("Pause");
         gameManager.DoSomething(true);
     }
     protected override void ChangeState(GameManager gameManager, PressedButton button)
     {
         gameManager.State = new WorkState();
     }
 }
```

GameManager.cs:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     internal GameState State { get; set; }

     ...

     void Start()
     {
         ...
         State = new StartState();
     }

     public void FindOut(PressedButton button)
     {
         State.HandleButton(this, button);
     }
     ...
 }
```

Но при запуске появляется ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это потому что я использую ключевое слово "new":

```
State = new StartState();
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Можно ли вообще таким образом реализовать паттерн "Состояние"? Как грамотно это сделать в Unity?

Comment: Вероятно из-за protected GameManager gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GameManager>(); - получай компонент  в Awake. Нельзя вешать абстрактные классы, у тебя есть StartState и др - вот их и вешай

Comment: Статистические поля кажется нельзя сериализировать

Comment: "Статистические поля кажется нельзя сериализировать."

@ValeraKvip, если к GameObject прикреплён скрипт, то да. Поля в инспекторе не отображаются.
А к самому скрипту прикрепить GameManager почему-то можно.
Я сам не знаю почему.

"у тебя есть StartState и др - вот их и вешай"  

Т.е. необходимо создать отдельный файл StartState.cs, т.к., несмотря на то, что уже есть файл GameState.cs, в котором не только абстрактный класс, но и конкретные реализации, создать Gameobject с именем " StartState", т.к. без него не будет работать Awake(), поместить туда инициализацию GameManager. Правильно?

Comment: 1. Один класс - один файл (В случае с Unity тем более). 2. не важно как называть GO, важно что на него навешивать. нужно навесить StartState скрипт и тогда в Awake получать компоненты из GameManager

Comment: @ValeraKvip,

"Один класс - один файл (В случае с Unity тем более)"
Понял.

"не важно как называть GO, важно что на него навешивать. нужно навесить StartState"

Да. Я хотел сделать акцент на том, что гипотетически, если состояний будет много, то под каждое состояние придётся создавать пустой GO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Unity классам не обязательно наследоваться от `MonoBehaviour`) реализация паттерна никак не отличается от классической. Вопрос только в том, как вы собираетесь эти состояния использовать.

Можете, например, создать какой-нибудь контроллер ввода InputManager, который в Update проверяет определённый кнопки и передаёт их внутрь вашего текущего состояния, чтобы оно как-то обработало ввод.

У вас будет один объект с InputManager, который на нём висит и всё. А сами "состояния" будут переключаться уже внутри него.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @M. Green.

"В Unity классам не обязательно наследоваться от MonoBehaviour"

Скорее всего из-за того, что скрипты создаются программно, автоматом добавляется наследование.  Для Gamestate.cs - соглашусь, не нужно. А для GameManager.cs - необходимо, и это не позволяет использовать там "new".

Comment: @michaellux, "не позволяет использовать там"? Что именно вам мешает? Через "new" просто нельзя создавать MonoBehaviour-ы, всё остальное работает, как и в обычных шарпах. А для создания нового экземпляра MonoBehaviour нужно добавлять его через AddComponent<T> конкретному объекту.